unable to trigger Azure logic app on VM creation
I'm trying to build  CI/CD automation that will be triggered only on VM creation.
I have created logic app and connect it to event grid on resource write success event type as a trigger then once logic app get triggered it will invoke runbook that run some script in the new virtual machine.
The problem I'm facing is that logic app get triggered on all write actions in subscription which makes the solution hard to troubleshoot, divergent from the main goal, and consume more.
The goal is to start ci/cd automation whenever a new VM is created (centralized approach on subscription level where VM names can be any name)
does logic app have a specific event grid filter to only have VM create event? if not is there another suggested azure service I can use?

Have you tried using Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write?

Creates a new virtual machine or updates an existing virtual machine

You can use the Trigger logic app when Azure Virtual Desktop starts example for inspiration. You can't use it as it is (it deals with Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action) but the idea is similar.
You can try using the following advanced filters:
{
    "operatorType": "StringIn",
    "key": "data.operationName",
    "values": [
        "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write"
    ]
},
{
    "operatorType": "StringIn",
    "key": "data.status",
    "values": [
        "Succeeded"
    ]
},
{
    "operatorType": "StringNotIn",
    "key": "data.previousProvisioningState",
    "values": [
        "Succeeded"
    ]
}


Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write covers both create and update VM which is not the goal.

@AXn there's nothing else you can use but Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write. As for filtering the events by only "create" (not "update") - that's why I added the data.previousProvisioningState not containing Succeeded filter to the example - this is just an idea (as I haven't performed any tests myself), to give you some ideas to check and try. The main approach should work, the minor details might be different.

If for some reason you can't make filtering work, you can always check whether this is a new machine or not after the event - it's much better than having the Logic App "triggered on all write actions in subscription".

seems still can not distinguish write and update, any more ideas?

@wenbo perhaps if you can share the event details (JSON)?

Hi @10p, I can find data.status, but not find data.previousProvisioningState when creating vm event issue.

@wenbo I can't advise much without seeing the event JSON. The original question was "to start ci/cd automation whenever a new VM is created" and not "on all write actions in subscription" - which my answer helps with. True, it might also be triggered when  the VM is updated, but given that there's no other event that can be used, this would be a minor inconvenience: even if the event details don't show if it's a create or an update operation, it can be easily checked further down in the workflow logic.

@10p, ok, I know, I was just somewhat interested in this question, so I took a quick look and your answer was also helpful. To make clear create or update may need more judgment via other ways not only the event which trigger the logicapp. Thanks man, you are good.
